# AuthenticationService.Authenticating

Tags: .net, forms-authentication

Will setting e.isAuthenticated to true be enough to set the forms authentication cookie?

this is in the AuthenticationService.Authenticating event of the wcf authentication service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've just recently tested this scenario and using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to view the headers showed that the `Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=` header variable was present. Another way to test is to add an event handler for the [CreatingCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.applicationservices.authenticationservice.creatingcookie.aspx) event, which occurs when the authentication cookie is being created.